# Interactive Form not writing to the data extension when the email is sent from a journey

Tags: marketing-cloud, cloudpage, form, interactive-email

Since I haven't worked with interactive forms before, I created a copy of an email that uses an interactive form someone else built. It has one button input that should pass hidden fields to the cloudpage when the recipient clicks on it. I didn't change anything about the form or cloudpage, which has successfully collected responses in the past, except to change the name of the data field containing the email address in the hidden fields.

When I send myself a test, the form collects data successfully and writes it to the data extension, but now that the journey is active, the formSubmit link has been clicked on by 4 people and none of their data has been written to the DE. Querying the data view shows that the LinkContent was: [https://submit.mc-content.com?utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=sm_email&utm_campaign=&sfmc_id=[subscriberkey]](https://submit.mc-content.com?utm_source=sfmc&utm_medium=sm_email&utm_campaign=&sfmc_id=%5Bsubscriberkey%5D)

I've checked the '00 IC Error Log' data extension and it doesn't have any recent entries, so I am completely at a loss for how to debug this. Any suggestions?